# How to do this in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, text-manipulation

I have thousands of lines that look like this:

```
Username | Password | Account Status | Region | Email | Summoner Name | BE | RP | RP Refunds | Level | Curr Rank | Prev Rank | Champs | Skins | Last Played
```

These fields are not literal strings, like "Email" is a real email, "Password" is a real password, "Username" is a real username, etc. Like `Needhelpx5 | xxxyyy | Valid` and so on

I want to make it look like this:

```
Email | Password
```

Example: Needhelpx5@yahoo.com | xxxyyy111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^|]+\|([^|]+)(?:\|[^|]+){2}\|([^|]+).+$`
- Replace with: `$2|$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                     # beginning of line
    [^|]+               # 1 or more any character that is not a pipe
    \|                  # a pipe
    ([^|]+)             # group 1, 1 or more any character that is not a pipe (i.e. password)
    (?:                 # non capture group
        \|                # a pipe
        [^|]+             # 1 or more any character that is not a pipe
    ){2}                # end group, must appear twice
    \|                  # a pipe
    ([^|]+)             # group 2, 1 or more any character that is not a pipe (i.e. email)
    .+                  # 1 or more any character but newline
$                     # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$2              # content of group 2 (email)
|               # a pipe
$1              # content of group 1 (password)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: God bless you and your entire family my man, it worked!!! <333

Comment: @Needhelpx5: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)